# Question about a set of Laplace-transforms

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, laplace-transform

A couple of years I asked in MSE about a set of Laplace-transforms getting no answer so far but got curious again yesterday. I'm putting the question here and as much focused as possible, just as a table - see the original problem description [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1096669/1714). It might well be a trivial question or be answered in some list of Laplace-transformations in some handbook by but I'm unfamiliar with the handling of Laplace-transformation and its inverse.

I have a set of series (coefficients in an infinite matrix somehow analoguous to a Carlemanmatrix) and found empirically that they seem to represent Laplace-transforms of a simple family of functions: see the list on the second column of the table. Only for the first series I found (heuristically, using Noerlund summation and small arguments $x$) a likely closed form for it: see third column in the table.

I used Pari/GP and the function `serlaplace()` and the function `psi(x)` for $\psi(x)$

$$ \begin{array} {c|clr}
\text{nr}&\text{the laplace-transformation} & =\text{closed form}\\
\hline
f_1(x):&\mathcal L( \log( {(\exp(x)-1) \over x})^1) \cdot{1 \over 1! } & = \log(\frac1x)-\psi(\frac1x) & \phantom {aaaaaaaaaaa}(1)\\
f_2(x):&\mathcal L( \log( {(\exp(x)-1) \over x})^2) \cdot{1 \over 2! } & = 
 \text {???} & \phantom {aaaaaaaaaaa}(2)\\
f_2(x):&\mathcal L( \log( {(\exp(x)-1) \over x})^3) \cdot{1 \over 3! } & = 
 \text {???} & \phantom {aaaaaaaaaaa}(3)\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{array}$$

> Q: Are there closed forms for $f_2(x),f_3(x),...$ ?
>   Q: Do they have a general expression in some memorizable pattern?

*(please add appropriate tags to the question as may fit)*

---

See an excerpt of the set of coefficients of the series, occuring column-wise in my matrix ***A*** (of infinite size):

$ \qquad $ [image: picture]

Comment: Since the $n$-th input is basically the $n$-the power of the first, the $n$-th output can be obtain by repeated convolution of the first output with itself. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Johannes - do you mean just to *iterate* the function, say $ f_2(x) = \log(f_1(x)) - \psi(f_1(x))$ ?

Comment: No, I mean taking the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution of $f_1$ with itself.

Comment: @Johannes - ah, I see, thanks for the hint. This is over my head at the moment, I can only study this in detail tomorrow.